# Meaning of the phrase 「想像をはるかに上回る」

Tags: translation

I am trying to understand the phrase 「想像をはるかに上回る」.

Here is the context:

There is an article / post whose contents are below.

> 私には夢があります。ずっと前から大切に持ち続けてきた夢なのです。
>
> several lines later……
>
> 私も蝿に生まれたかったです！

In response to this, someone replied:

> 想像をはるかに上回る願望…笑

According to [thesaurus.weblio.jp](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BA%88%E6%83%B3%E3%82%92%E3%81%AF%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AB%E4%B8%8A%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B), among the synonyms for a similar phrase, 「予想をはるかに上回る」, is 「想像もつかない」. Looking at this, one might guess that the whole reply could be translated as "a dream that exceeds all imagination" or "a dream far beyond my imagination."

However, if this is correct, I am still not sure how that fits into the context. It seems to me that there are still several possibilities.

- "I did not see (imagine) that coming."
- "I cannot imagine why you would dream such a thing."
- "I cannot imagine having that dream come true and living life as a fly."

Comment: I think you quite get it. 願望 is desir/ambition, 上回る is to exeed and はるかに is here to express the fact that it exeeds imagination (想像) in a great extent. I think that "想像をはるかに上回る願望…笑" is just sarcastic and could be glossed by "What a dream, man!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be answered in a word -- "irony".

> [想像]{そうぞう}をはるかに[上回]{うわまわ}る[願望]{がんぼう}…[笑]{わら}

The phrase is not to be taken literally.  The 「笑 (= lol)」 part at the end should serve as a big hint.  The speaker/author expects the listeners to laugh at the statement.

One of your interpretations: "I did not see (imagine) that coming." would fit right in.  (The other two sound kinda too "serious" IMHO even though those are what is actually meant by the speaker.)

Comment: Judging by the way [笑]{わら} is being used in that sentence, wouldn’t it be read as わら instead of しょう (as shown [here](http://jisho.org/word/%EF%BD%97))?

Comment: It's not わら of the root of 笑う as a verb. It should be read わらい as a noun, meaning laughter.

Comment: The character, 笑 is pronounced ‘しょう‐shou’ when it’s combined with modifying words, such as 微笑 (smile)、哄笑 (loud laughter)、苦笑 (wry smile)、笑話(comical story), but never pronounced しょう when it’s used alone in a single character. It should be pronounced as ‘わらい,’ not わら、which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: そう言われましても大勢の人がそう読んでしまってるんだから仕方ないのでは・・・所詮ネット用語ですし・・・「ﾜﾗ」「[藁]{ワラ}」「ワロス」「ワラタ」「[氏]{し}ね」「[ネ申]{かみ}」「[タヒ]{し}」「[禿]{はげ}しく同意」などなど、もう何でもアリって感じですし・・

Comment: I'm surprised to hear many people are reading and uttering so. Recentry the Asahi Newspaper introduced the word "オワコン,” with which” I had no idea, under the headline, "五輪はオワコンか？,” and found out it means "終わったコンテンツ," as I went ahead the article, Japanese language is becoming the Tower of Babel even among Japanese these days..

Answer (score 2):

On top of three alternatives you proposed, I would put the last Japanese lines you quoted into the following dialogue, as just one of variations:

A. I have a dream, the dream that I have cherished long, long time.
I wish I had been born a fly.

B. It's a wish far beyond my imagination! (laughter).

Answer (score 0):

"Your wishes/desires are beyond what anyone would imagine, lol"

...is my interpretation.

Or to put in another way "I can't imagine wanting to be a fly, lol"

想像 (imaginations)
はるかに上回る (far exceed)
願望 (wish/desire)
笑 (lol)

The only part in the response that refers to the original context is the 願望 (of the original writer). Everything else corresponds to the responding person's opinion.